# Holes on my succulent leaves

Tags: houseplants, diseases, succulents

[image]

Hi, my succulents have recently been getting holes in them and I have no idea what it is. 
Please help!!

Comment: Do you have a cat?

Comment: nope, no pets at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar marks on several succulents outdoors and the damage was from grasshoppers.  Apparently mice and rats, earwigs, and slugs can cause similar damage. 
Also spikes from other succulents can cause holes and scars.,

Comment: thankyou, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar marks on the underside of lower leaves and they turned out to be snails. Would come out of soil at night to feed.  Check for snails after dark with flash light.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that can cause marks on Echeveria leaves.   Some people have already mentioned slugs and other larger pest eating the leaves.  It can be abrasions from being handled, like from your hand, your nails, rings on your fingers.  I have cause damage to mine with my wedding ring.  I have also created abrasions with my nails or rubbing the plant against another plant or the wall it is pushed against. 
I can not tell from your picture if they are raised marks or indents.  You call them hole, so I am assuming indents.  If the marks are raised it could be Oedema.  This is caused by over watering.

[Commons signs and symptoms of various succulent problems](https://debraleebaldwin.com/uh-oh-succulent-sick/)